# What is the usage of catch in this C++ code

Tags: c++, operators, try-catch

Hi I am very new to `C++` programming, and I am really hard to understand the code below in which they have used `catch`. So I want to know why do they use `catch` in this code. Thanks in advance

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <exception>
 using namespace std;
 int main () 
 {
 try
 {
  int* myarray = new int[1000];
  cout << "allocated";
 }
 catch (exception& e)
 {
    cout << "Standard exception: " << e.what() << endl;
   }
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator [`new`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) may throw an exception in case it cannot allocate the required space.

From the link above:

```
throwing (1)    void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc);
```

> Throws bad_alloc if it fails to allocate storage. Otherwise, it throws
>   no exceptions (no-throw guarantee).

Comment: Note that when `new` allocates an instance of a struct/class, or `new[]` allocates an array of struct/class elements, the memory might allocate OK, but the struct/class constructor may throw its own exceptions. That is not the case in this example, as it is allocating an array of a fundamental type. But it is something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The statements in `catch` will be executed when one of the statements in the `try` block throws an exception. This tutorial link will helps a ton: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

try and catch come inside exception handling in C++

```
  try
{

 int* myarray = new int[1000];

    cout << "allocated";
}

catch (exception& e)
{

cout << "Standard exception: " << e.what() << endl;

}
```

in this case first it wil check the memory allocation using try block and if it fail to allocate the memory  then using catch it will throw exception,that memory could not be allocated